# How to add a space between a string for every 5th letter?

Tags: python

Hey, I'm trying to figure out how to input a space between every fifth letter in my program after the computer asks how many coins they would like. So this is what it looks like currently.

```
pile1_str = "pile 1: "
x="O"
y=1
while y <= pile1:   #pile1 being the number of chips the user inputs     
    pile1_str = pile1_str + x
    print(pile1_str)
    y= y+1
```

Here's what it's supposed to look like when you input, say 12 coins:

`pile 1: OOOOO OOOOO OO`

What can I do to insert a space in the string after every n-th (5th) character?

Comment: So what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pile1_str = "pile 1: "
x="O"
y=1
while y <= pile1:
    pile1_str = pile1_str + x
    if y%1==0:
        pile1_str = pile1_str + " "
    print(pile1_str)
    y= y+1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
length = 19
groupSize = 5
pile = 'O' * length
spacedPile = ' '.join(pile[i:i+groupSize] for i in xrange(0, len(pile), groupSize))
print spacedPile
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.